# Multilingual Wordpress custom wp-login form with WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

In my custom Wordpress theme, I have custom login form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php" name="login">
    <div class="login-form-container resp-hidden">
        <div class="login-form-container-inner">
            <h3 class="form-title"><?php echo __('Login', 'louise'); ?></h3>

            <label for="user_login">
                <?php echo __('User name or e-mail', 'louise'); ?>: </label>
            <input class="para-content" type="text" name="log" placeholder="" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login, $user_email)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="11" required>

            <label for="user_pass">
                <?php echo __('Password', 'louise'); ?>: </label>
            <input class="para-content" type="password" name="pwd" value="" size="20" id="user_pass" tabindex="12" required/>
            <label for="rememberme"> </label>

            <div class="buttons">
                <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php echo __('Log in', 'louise'); ?>" tabindex="14" class="signupbtn" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo icl_get_home_url() ; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It gets the job done, but problem appears when I am trying to log in from different than default language. Login redirects to the front-page leaving with inactive URL: http://test.com/**?lang=en/wp-login.php** I am using WPML plugin for two languages, default one is lt_LT and en_US as additional.

I was digging threw all the weekend, but found no valid solution. To make it clear, I don't get if I have to translate core WP wp-login.php page, o is there a shortcut to bypass wp-login.php and redirect user straight to home page?

Many thanks for all possible help and suggestions.

Looking forward,

Answer (score 1):

First change the form action to

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

and use this PHP after the form

```
if (isset($_POST['user-submit'])) {
    login_auth($_POST['log'], $_POST['pwd']);
}
```

and add this function to `functions.php`

```
function login_auth( $username, $password ) {
  global $user;

  $current_cookie = esc_attr( $_COOKIE['_icl_current_language'] );
  $url = '/'.$current_cookie;
  $login_page = site_url($url);    

  $creds = array();
  $creds['user_login'] = $username;
  $creds['user_password'] =  $password;
  $creds['remember'] = true;
  $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
  if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
    echo $user->get_error_message();
  }
  if ( !is_wp_error($user) ) {
    wp_redirect($login_page);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @Mo'menMohamed . I have tried your solution, but problem still exists. User can't login when secondary language is turned on.

Comment: What exactly is wrong?
 An error message appears or is not logged in

Comment: No error message, it redirects to home page with default language set.

Comment: I have, but still no results :/ no error message, I can login while in default language, but getting redirected when trying to login in secondary language.

Comment: check this https://wpml.org/forums/topic/login-page-redirection-using-icl_language_code/

Comment: Seems in this topic language URL format is set for: **Different languages in directories** while in my case language URL format is **Language name added as a parametet** I have tried to reuse code and wrote : 
if ( $current_cookie == 'en' ){
        $login_page = site_url("/wp-login.php/?lang=en/");}

Comment: _extension of the last comment_

Could you say if it is the correct url? It made no effect for login in English. Furthermore, with this code working I could't logout from my account, it redirected me to the `/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2&_wpnonce=7c732d6b90` 

Here is the code used for login:

`<h3><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( icl_get_home_url()  ); ?>">
                    <?php echo __('Log out','louise'); ?>
                </a></h3>`

Comment: replace this line wp_redirect($login_page); with this wp_redirect(icl_get_home_url());

Answer (score 0):

After all, here is my solution that worked in my case. Seems, that the problem was language parameter set by WPML plugin. It is possible to check if current link has `?lang=en/` and change it with default wp-login url.

```
<?php
    if($login = strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?lang=en")) {
                    $login = wp_login_url();
                    } else {
                    $login = wp_login_url();
                    }?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $login?>"
    <div class="login-form-container resp-hidden">
        <div class="login-form-container-inner">
            <h3 class="form-title"><?php echo __('Login', 'louise'); ?></h3>

            <label for="user_login">
                <?php echo __('User name or e-mail', 'louise'); ?>: </label>
            <input class="para-content" type="text" name="log" placeholder="" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login || $user_email)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="11" required>

            <label for="user_pass">
                <?php echo __('Password', 'louise'); ?>: </label>
            <input class="para-content" type="password" name="pwd" value="" size="20" id="user_pass" tabindex="12" required/>
            <label for="rememberme"> </label>

            <div class="buttons">
                <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php echo __('Log in', 'louise'); ?>" tabindex="14" class="signupbtn" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```